# Web data entry forms from database tables

Tags: database, web, forms

Is there any development framework that, having a database, tables, relationships,

- take the tables as inputs and generates web data entry forms to edit the records,
- AND provides tools to BROWSE, ADD, MODIFY, DELETE and PRINT the records and tables?

Years ago I did something similar with symfony, but it reached a dead end due to the complexity of symfony. Yesterday I've found https://phpdatabaseform.com/, but it does not provide tools to interact with all the table results, just with a single record.

Obviously, I would prefer opensource, standard databases (MariaDB, MongoDB, Postgresql, etc.) and something more versatile as nodejs as a backend, not php.

Please be gentle, I am a programmer, but don't know almost nothing about web design. Thanks in advance!